# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on string

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to execute a query and iterate thru the result. The `echo "<h1>" . $row["SummonerId"]. "</h1>";` works and it print it out at the page. But somehow this Error occurred after the printed result:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on string

I saw many errors similar to this. But those are `on a non-object` and not `on string`. What is that error?

Here is my code:

```
$servername = "localhost:3307";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "st-datacollector";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM summoner";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h1>" . $row["SummonerId"]. "</h1>";  
        $summonerId = $row["SummonerId"];
        $url = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/game/by-summoner/" . $summonerId . "/recent?api_key=" . $api_key;

        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        $resultJSON = json_decode($result);


        foreach($resultJSON_decoded->games as $game){
            echo $game->gameMode." ".$game->gameType." ".$game->subType;
            echo "<br>";
        }           
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: A string is a non-object.

Comment: In the code in your question, `fetch_assoc()` is not used after `$row["SummonerId"]` is output, and `$result` cannot be a string, so it seems impossible for it to produce this specific error. Is there more code not included?

Comment: Yeah, I am not seeing how this could be producing this error.

Comment: That error message goes with this code? `$mysqli` is not assigned.

Comment: If `$result` was a string, the `$result->fetch_assoc()` would not have executed at all because it wouldn't make it past `$result->num_rows` without an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$result` variable is used to loop thru mysql query, you have to use different variable names inside your loop

```
$servername = "localhost:3307";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "st-datacollector";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM summoner";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h1>" . $row["SummonerId"]. "</h1>";  
        $summonerId = $row["SummonerId"];
        $url = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/game/by-summoner/" . $summonerId . "/recent?api_key=" . $api_key;

        $fcontents = file_get_contents($url);
        $resultJSON = json_decode($fcontents);

        foreach($resultJSON_decoded->games as $game){
            echo $game->gameMode." ".$game->gameType." ".$game->subType;
            echo "<br>";
        }           
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

One more little thing I noticed.. `$resultJSON` and `$resultJSON_decoded` doesn't match inside the loop