# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on string

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Can anyone help me solve this?  I having this line code with error of

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on string in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dbcontroller.php on line 26

Line 26 is this line of code: $result = $query->fetch_assoc();

```
<?php
class DBController {
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $password = " ";
private $database = "test";

function __construct() {
    $conn = $this->connectDB();
    if(!empty($conn)) {
        $this->selectDB($conn);
    }
}

function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
    return $conn;
}

function selectDB($conn) {
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$this->database);
}


function runQuery($query) {
    $result = $query->fetch_assoc();
    // $result = mysqli_query($query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
}

function numRows($query) {
    $result  = mysqli_query($query);
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    return $rowcount;   
}
}
?>
```

Comment: mysqli_query first argument is connection object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch\_assoc() on string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849960/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-string)

Comment: so what should I do?  I'm very new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncomment the code line -

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

And comment this line -

```
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

For not getting this error.

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ajax-add-edit-delete-records-in-database-using-php-and-jquery\dbcontroller.php on line 27
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ajax-add-edit-delete-records-in-database-using-php-and-jquery\dbcontroller.php on line 28

Comment: Rahul, this happened after I uncomment the line u mentioned and comment the line you suggested.

Comment: I apologize for that, the right syntax will be - $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. You cannot call functions in strings, e.g.

```
// Wrong
$name = 'Johnny';
echo $name->foo();
```

In your case:

```
function runQuery($query) {
    $result = $query->fetch_assoc();
    // [...]
}
```

... you don't say what `$query` contains but context suggest's is a string with SQL code. Simply, that's now how mysqli extension is used. Feel free to have a look at [the manual](http://php.net/mysqli) and see some [usage examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an argument to this.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I changed your code, Now try.   
<?php
    class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = " ";
    private $database = "test";

    function __construct() {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        if(!empty($conn)) {
            $this->selectDB($conn);
        }
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
        return $conn;
    }

    function selectDB($conn) {
        mysqli_select_db($conn,$this->database);
    }


    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($query);
        while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
    }
    ?>
```